# Detecting ajax:failure in Rails 3 forms

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working with a form in rails 3 and I am running into a totally weird situation.
Basically, the form detects a successful return, but fails to detect a "400" error.  Here is some code.

JQUERY:

```
$(".editorial_review").live('ajax:failure', function(xhr, status, error) {
         alert('error');
        })
    .live('ajax:success', function(){$(this).parents('tr').prev('tr.main').fadeOut(); $(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(); });
  });
```

RAILS:

```
 def create
    render :json => {:error => 'No Final Status Selected'},:status => 400 and return if params[:status].blank?
    @success = send(params[:status].gsub(' ', '_'))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {head:ok}
    end
  end
```

HAML:

```
-semantic_form_for EditorialReview.new, :remote=>true do |f|
```

I've checked in firebug, and everything seems kosher, and indeed when the controller responds with `head :ok` there are no problems to speak of.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jquery rails.js uses `ajax:error` instead of `ajax:failure`. Try that